# Properties of odd and even functions

Tags: functions

I found two statements for even and odd functions:

1. If $f(x)$ is an even function then $ c*f(a*x)$ is also an even function, where a and c are nonzero real numbers.
2. If $f(x)$ is an odd function, then $f(x)+d$ is an odd function, where d is a nonzero real number.

I am aware that the 1st one is correct and the 2nd one is false, because I tried with $ x^2, 1/x, \sin(x)$. But I do not know how to prove it in general for all functions. Can someone help me ?

Comment: I think you would be done with the proof that 2. is incorrect since all you need is one counterexample.

Comment: @Shine On You Crazy Diamond okay thank you! But do you have an answer for the first one as well?

Comment: To prove the first, simply apply the definition of *even function.*

Answer (score 1):

$g:x\mapsto f(x)+d \;$ is odd  if

$$f(-x)+d=-(f(x)+d)$$
$$=-f(x)-d$$

but
$$f(-x)=-f(x)$$
since $f$ is odd.

thus necessarily
$$d=-d \text{ or } d=0.$$

remark that if $ f $ is even, then $ g $ is also even.

Answer (score 1):

To prove that a function $g$ is even, you need to show that $g(-x) = g(x)$ for every $x.$

For part 1, You are given an even function $f.$
Therefore $f(-x) = f(x)$ for every $x.$
Now you are asked about another function of $x$ whose rule is that it maps $x$ to $cf(ax).$

It may help to write $g(x) = cf(ax)$ and then show that $g$ is even,
because it may be easier to see how $g(x)$ is a function of $x$ than to see
how $cf(ax)$ is a function of $x.$
Then you would just have to show that $g(-x) = g(x)$ for every $x$
in order to prove that $g$ is even.